# How do I capture the text that is before and after a multiple regex matches in java?

Tags: java, regex

Given a test string of:

```
I have a 1234 and a 2345 and maybe a 3456 id.
```

I would like to match all the IDs (the four digit numbers) AND at the same time get 12 characters of their surrounding text (before and after) (if any!)

So the matches should be:

```
             BEFORE       MATCH      AFTER
Match #1:   I have a-      1234    -and a 2345-
Match #2:   -1234 and a-   2345    -and maybe a
Match #3:   and maybe a-   3456    -id.

This (-) is a space character
```

#### Note:

The BEFORE match of Match #1 is not 12 characters long (not many characters at the beginning of the string). Same with the AFTER match of Match #3  (not many characters after the last match)

Can I achieve these matches with a single regex in java?

My best attempt so far is to use a positive look behind and an atomic group (to get the surrounding text) but it fails in the beginning and the end of the string when there are not enough characters (like my **note** above)

```
(?<=(.{12}))(\d{4})(?>(.{12}))
```

This matches only 2345.  If I use a small enough value for the quantifiers (2 instead of 12, for example) then I correctly match all IDs.

Here is a link to my regex playground where I was trying my regex's:

http://regex101.com/r/cZ6wG4

Comment: Is there a practical limit to the length of the texts before and after the matches?

Comment: Well, this is a contrived example just to demonstrate the issues I have. In reality I will need to match around 200-300 characters before  and after each match.  Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the MatchResult (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html) interface implemented by the Matcher class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) you will find the functions `start()` and `end()` which give you the index of the first / last character of the match within the input string. Once you have the indicies, you can use some simple math and the substring function to extract the parts you want.

I hope this helps you, because I won't write the entire code for you.

There might be a possibility to do what you want purely with regex. But I think using the indicies and substring is easier (and probably more reliable)

Comment: So basically you're saying to match only in the IDs (\d{4}) and then get the BEFORE and AFTER text with substrings() requests with java code?

Comment: @Stratosgear exactly, a purely regex solution seems unpractical (and is probably slower)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=^.{0,10000}?(.{0,12}))(\\d+)(?=(.{0,12}))");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    before = regexMatcher.group(1);
    match = regexMatcher.group(2);
    after = regexMatcher.group(3);
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=          # Assert that the following can be matched before current position
 ^.{0,10000}? # Match as few characters as possible from the start of the string
 (.{0,12})    # Match and capture up to 12 chars in group 1
)             # End of lookbehind
(\d+)         # Match and capture in group 2: Any number
(?=           # Assert that the following can be matched here:
 (.*)         # Match and capture up to 12 chars in group 3
)             # End of lookahead
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work with the lookbehind? The regex101.com online regexer complains that: {0,10000} Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed!!  http://regex101.com/r/oX9yH0  Maybe a limitation of the online parser?

Comment: @Stratosgear: That's a PCRE limitation, Java does tolerate finite repetition in lookbehinds.

Comment: I just noticed that you're just looking for up to 12 characters. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: `before` will be empty. It seems that look-behind is making `.{0,12}` reluctant. I even tried to rewrite it to make it start matching from biggest number of occurrences using string like `.{12}|.{11}| ... |.{1}|.{0}"` but this also act same way.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this happens because look-behind starts to test at position right before match so in case of `|123` (where `|` represents position where look-behind start testing) empty string would be only possible result, so to prevent it we could use `(?<=(.{0,12})\\2)` but unfortunately `\\2` can't be used in negative-look-behind.

Comment: Only working solution I found was `(?<=^.{0,100000}?(.{0,12}))` but traversing from beginning of string each time seems inefficient.

Comment: Actually lets forget about `\\2`, it couldn't help us anyway (I don't know what I was thinking).

Comment: @Pshemo: Oops, yes. Updated regex...it's inefficient for sure, but if the constraints involve a regex-only solution, there's not much we can do.

Comment: @Stratosgear `(?<=^.{0,100000}?(.{0,12}))` would traverse till beginning of string and then select last 12 characters (or less if not possible) so this is kind of inefficient. Instead you should use advice from [x4rf41 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24434796/1393766) and manually substring interesting part based on position of ID you found (using `start()`, `end()` methods from Matcher class).

Comment: It seemed like a simple task (finding the surrounding text of match) but if you guys can't find a single regex that can do it (judging by your SO scores and profiles) I believe it is not possible after all.  Writing a couple of extra lines of java code as x4rf41 mentioned below does not look as such a bad idea anymore... :)

Comment: @Stratosgear We ware able to do it :) but not in efficient way :(

Comment: @Pshemo No insult intended :) I just don't consider such a solution acceptable due to the level of inefficiency, that's all.

Comment: @Stratosgear No insult taken, was just clarifying things :)

Comment: @Stratosgear: I agree. In .NET, an efficient regex solution is possible, but lookbehind assertions are rather limited in most regex implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lookbehind or an atomic group for this, but you do need a lookahead:

```
(.{0,12}?)\b(\d+)\b(?=(.{0,12}))
```

I'm assuming your ID's are not enclosed in longer words (thus the `\b`).  I used a reluctant quantifier in the leading portion (`{0,12}?`) to prevent it consuming more than one ID when they're spaced close to each other, and in:

```
I have a 1234, 2345 and 1456 id.
```

Comment: This will prevent reusing already matched values in `before` part so instead of `Match #2: -1234 and a-...` you will get `Match #2: -and a-...`